# PCとスマホをリダイレクトする.htaccesの設定について

Tags: .htaccess

PCサイトとスマホサイトのURLが異なるため、リダイレクトさせようとして、`.htaccess`に以下のように記述しサーバーのルートドメインのみセットしました。

スマホでPCトップページにアクセスするとうまく切り替わったのですが、PC下層ページが反映されません（スマホページに切り替わらない）。スマホサイトのトップページから下層ページに遷移すると（当然ですが）きちんとスマホサイトがでます。PC下層ページを直入力するとスマホ下層ページに切り替わりません。何が間違っているのか教えていただけませんでしょうか。

`.htaccess`の記述は以下の通りです。

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iPhone|Android.*Mobile|Windows.*Phone) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !mode=pc
RewriteRule ^$ /smt/ [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

URLは以下の通りです。

＜TOP＞
PCサイト　`http://www.〇〇〇.com/` もしくは　`http://www.〇〇〇.com/index.html`
スマホサイト　`http://www.〇〇〇.com/smt`

＜下層＞
PCサイト　`http://www.〇〇〇.com/△△△.html`
スマホサイト　`http://www.〇〇〇.com/smt/△△△.html`

お手数になりますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess の場合、パス「/a/b/c.html」の先頭の「/」が省かれた「a/b/c.html」が `RewriteRule` の対象となります。
現在の設定の `^$` だと、パス「/」のみを対象としていますので、トップページのみとなります。
正規表現、後方参照、あと、リダイレクトループにならないよう「/smt/」を除外するルールを考えてみてください。

(追記)
「/何らかのパス」→「/smt/何らかのパス」にするならば、以下の設定です。

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /smt/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。大変恐縮なのですが、正規表現を調べていますが、書き方がわかりません。TOPページ＝「/a.html」と「/a」の混合で、下層は「/a/b/c.html」なのですが、これをすべて含む書き方か、そのヒントを教えていただけませんでしょうか。